# Highlight partial HTML table row

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, highlight

I have a table as follows in HTML:

```
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>col1</td>
   <td>col2</td>
   <td>col3</td>
   <td>col4</td>
   <td>col5</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

At the moment, I have a rollover and click on the entire row so when I move over it with my mouse the background color changes and when I click on any column an event happens.

My question is as follows, I now see that it would be helpful to change this layout and upon mouseover only highlight columns 3-5 and the click there would execute the same event but when I click on a name in column one or column 2 it would go to the URL for that name.

Essentially, I am trying to find out if it is possible to limit the table row highlight to just columns 3-5 and then have a click on any of those columns trigger the event.

Would the solution be to put rows 3-5 inside a span? That does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How abt using `:gt()` selector. [From the docs](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) :

> Select all elements at an index greater than index within the matched set.

Note that `gt` is zero based, so to highlight columns 3 -5, you'll need to use `index` as 1.

**JS :**

```
$("tr").on("mouseover mouseout", function () {
    $(this).find("td:gt(1)").toggleClass("highlight");
});
```

**CSS**

```
.highlight {
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/rJZbn/

Comment: I know.. was just providing an alternative to your answer :)

Comment: Interestingly, `gt` is faster for me on my PC - using Chrome 28 @Blade0rz :)

Comment: @hungerpain Definitely interesting! My Chrome 28 returns :gt() as being 59% slower

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's [slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to add a class to a certain subset of columns:

```
$("tr").hover(function() {
  $(this).find("td").slice(2,5).addClass("hovering");
}, function() {
  $(this).find("td").removeClass("hovering");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a **only css** solution:

```
table tr td:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+5) {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child
See the last example